# Searching for a deity of water and fire?

Tags: pantheon

The title says it (almost) all.

I'm searching for a deity whose aspects are **BOTH** fire and water. Any religion/pantheon is ok.

It could be a greater spirit or something like that, but I prefer a god.

Edit 1: I'm looking for a deity that whose domains are exclusively fire and water. No omnipotence and other bigger stuff.

Comment: This is broad.  Don't most religions have an omnipotent deity who, by definition, covers fire, water and everything else?

Comment: Hmmm, I know it is... Will edit question so I clarify some stuff

Comment: The Basque [Eate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eate) and the Celtic [Grannus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grannus) might be close to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yannis on the rignt track: the Celts had a number of deities whose healing power combined a solar element with water: Grannus, [Sul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulis), Brigit and [Borvo/Bormanus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borvo). (The Brigit lore relates mainly to the saint, as a number of [healing wells](http://irelandsholywells.blogspot.ca/2014/01/saint-brigids-well-liscannor-county.html) were sacred to her, and an [everlasting flame](https://sacredsitetour.com/kildare-and-brighid-sacredsites-ireland) was kept at her sanctuary in Kildare. But it's assumed that the lore is a continuation of earlier beliefs.)

The deity [Apam Napat](http://www.iranicaonline.org/articles/apam-napat), who appears in Zoroastrian texts and the Hindu Vedas, is another contender. Although he's the son of the waters, the Indian texts [associate him](http://www.apamnapat.com/entities/ApamNapat.html) with the fire-god Agni. One theory is that [he represents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apam_Napat) fire in the water, a sort of stored fire.

Comment: Agni is exclusively a fire god.